# How to let a boolean field on NULL if untouched?

Tags: 9

Steps to reproduce my issue :

1- Add a boolean field to Article content type, not required, without touching default value

2- Edit an Article content without touching the boolean field.

3- Save the content.

4- The boolean field displays now FALSE value.

How to let this boolean field untouched and without any value (and thus hidden on full content display)?

Comment: I would say that’s by design - a Boolean can only represent true or false, not a third value. A list field with a “N/A” option and complementary template logic might make more sense conceptually

Comment: That makes sense indeed. But nodes created with Feeds import do not display boolean fields even if they should probably be on False too. So I was wondering if there would be a way to let the boolean field "empty" like Feeds does.

Comment: That makes sense - if memory serves, it’s either the field widget or the checkbox element which casts the value to a bool when processed. So while you have the field on the form, I think it’ll be a bit awkward to change that logic

Comment: I guess that logic is inappropriate in my case. The boolean field "Hydrophobe", for example, is set to "No" by default but my client can not tell until it has been tested. So I suppose I should switch to a List Text with three options (Not tested yet, Yes, No) as you suggested earlier. And I have 20 boolean fields...

Comment: Yikes - another option might be to extend the core Boolean field with a custom type and see if you can intercept the part which does the casting

Comment: It was my mistake at the beginning of the content type creation, wrong choice. Thanks for sharing your thoughts anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible in the boolean field, it is possible to select the list field.

- Create a list(text) field. It should be a single value to act as a radio button.
- Change its widget from manage form display from the select list to checkbox/radio.

When you submit a node without touching the field it will have a null value.